# What is sent and received from the server during a "heartbeat" and how often does it beat?

Tags: discussion, live-refresh

In a previous question regarding [how auto drafts are saved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111050/what-are-the-details-implementation-of-the-draft-feature), waffles indicated that [the draft is sent to the server during the heartbeat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111050/what-are-the-details-implementation-of-the-draft-feature/111578#111578).

That said, the questions are:

- How often is the heartbeat sent?
- What is sent to the server?
- What is received from the server?

I've been able to gather the following:

- Answers have been posted - [How does SO give the “answers have been posted” notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71761/how-does-so-give-the-answers-have-been-posted-notification)
- Auto-drafts for new posts - [What are the details/implementation of the draft feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111050/what-are-the-details-implementation-of-the-draft-feature/111578#111578)
- Indicator of ongoing edits - [Indicator of an ongoing edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106565/indicator-of-an-ongoing-edit/107412#107412)

What's missing?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ: Fair enough, but isn't one of the points of Meta to have this information documented so not everyone has to ascertain it for themselves (and get it wrong or miss something)?  And I use Chrome, not Firefox (but I can use Fiddler). =)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the usual case (meaning you're using only one editor and not several, e.g. because you're answering a question while also editing it and another answer etc.) -- the heartbeat happens every 45 seconds.

It sends the following:

- Whether you're writing a question, an answer, or are editing a post
- When answering, it sends the Id of the question you're answering. When editing, it sends the Id of the post that's being edited.
- When answering, it sends information about what other answers the client (i.e. your browser) already knows about (see below)
- If you're asking or answering, and you have changed something since the previous heartbeat, it sends the full text of the post (and, if applicable, title and tags)

The server saves the draft, and returns the following to the client:

- When asking, it returns a list of "similar questions" that's shown in the sidebar
- When answering, it checks whether the question has been deleted, locked, or closed in the meantime (you have certainly seen the "this post has been closed; no more answers will be accepted" message before – this is where it comes from)
- When answering, it checks whether there are answers that the client doesn't know about yet (see above), so you get the "2 new answers have been posted" message
- When editing, it checks whether the post has been locked or deleted, or has been edited in the meantime ("This post has been edited 1 time since you began").

Random trivia: The heartbeat is controlled by an object called `StackExchange.cardiologist`.

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer! I assume you call the error handler "HeartAttack"? ;)

Comment: @balpha: `StackExchange.cardiologist` is a pretty GDLK name.

Answer (score -1):

The heartbeat is sent about once a minute, according to the very question you linked to.