# The edit of an existing answer is used to fill the "Your Answer" field

Tags: support, answers, edits

I edited an answer on [How can I get the 2012 April Fool's joke to appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127701/how-can-i-get-the-2012-april-fools-joke-to-appear) to show as screenshot the image for which the user provided a link on an external site.

After I did the edit, "Your answer" contained the text of the answer I was editing.

[image: screenshot]

Why is it happening?

I am using Safari 5.1.5 on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since

1. we don't save drafts of edits at all, and
2. your edit was quick enough so that it never even sent a heartbeat to the server (which is [what draft saving piggybacks on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111644/115866)),

this definitely has nothing to do with drafts. My guess is that maybe you're running a userscript etc. that has a bug, or that your browser does some "smart" (and wrong) autofill thing here.

I cannot 100% rule out a JavaScript bug on our side, but given how the several editors within a single page work together (or rather: *don't* work together), I consider this very unlikely

Comment: I don't have any userscript, or Safari extension installed. It could be some "smart" autofill, but this is the first time I have seen this; maybe Safari 5.1.5 is less smart (or try to be smarter) than previous versions. `:)`