# The cardiologist can't tell if my heart is beating!

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript

I have found a... strange, to say the least, error on Stack Overflow. I was just browsing normally and I decided to open the error console, and I saw this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isHeartBeating' of undefined
```

I thought that was a bit odd, so I found the line on which the error was:

```
StackExchange.cardiologist.isHeartBeating()
```

Stack Exchange has a cardiologist? And it *can't tell if my heart is beating*?! Are we in a Q&A site or an inexperienced hospital?

Here is some context for that code:

```
case "answer-add":0==$("#answer-"+d.answerid).length&&(p.push(d.answerid),StackExchange.cardiologist.isHeartBeating()?StackExchange.helpers.DelayedReaction(k,5E3).trigger():k(),StackExchange.cardiologist.notifiedOfNewAnswer());break;
```

And here it is more readable:

```
case "answer-add":
  0 == $("#answer-"+d.answerid).length &&
    (p.push(d.answerid),
    StackExchange.cardiologist.isHeartBeating() ?
    StackExchange.helpers.DelayedReaction(k,5E3).trigger() :
    k(),StackExchange.cardiologist.notifiedOfNewAnswer());
break;
```

And here it is from [the dev code](http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js):

```
function postAnswerAdd(post) {
    if ($('#answer-' + post.answerid).length != 0) return;

    answersToShow.push(post.answerid);

    if (StackExchange.cardiologist.isHeartBeating()) {
        var newAnswers = StackExchange.helpers.DelayedReaction(showNewAnswerNotification, 5000);
        newAnswers.trigger();
    } else {
        showNewAnswerNotification();
    }

    StackExchange.cardiologist.notifiedOfNewAnswer();
}
```

---

What is this strange error?

*(note: it is on line 18 of https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=2cb347042411)*

Comment: Probably some appropriately named function to see if you're around.

Comment: thanks @Antony, I never knew that was there

Comment: @Antony but it is much funnier watching people un-minifiy by hand!

Comment: @Doorknob for development purposes it is actually multiple sensibly sized / scoped scripts; we combine, minify, and cdn-push as part of deployment

Comment: for now I'll add a "Is there a doctor in the house?" check before expecting said medic to jump in "stat", but I'll need to check (with a colleague) what the intended behavior was there...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111581/what-is-sent-and-received-from-the-server-during-a-heartbeat-and-how-often-doe/111644#111644

Comment: Oh, and I also explain in a comment why I chose that name: `// I would have called it "heartbeatManager", but the boss doesn't like that: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/03/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager.html`

Comment: RIP my house security. There is no doorknob now. :S

Comment: He's dead, Jim.

Comment: And here I expected to see this title was a bad analogy! Imagine my surprise to see it was literal!

Comment: Full source for the `cardiologist` is [here](http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/wmd.js).

Comment: Please tell if you are in need of CPR.

Comment: `// There can be several hearts in a page`. I approve of this Time Lord technology

Comment: @balpha Having trouble [coming up with a class name](http://www.classnamer.com/)?

Comment: @Manishearth Where did you find that code? Do you happen to have the code for `StackExchange.realtime`? (I am building a greasemonkey script to help me answer more effeciently :P)

Comment: @Doorknob: Replace `wmd.js` with the name of the JS file that the SE object is on. I think it's `stub.js`. The code basically is what runs on dev.stackoverflow.com and dev.meta.SO.

Comment: @MarcGravell So wait... did you do that? Is this [status-completed]?

Comment: @Doorknob yes he did

Comment: I think heartbeat is a technical term in computer systems. See the following definition. http://computer.yourdictionary.com/heartbeat

Comment: I just got 10k, and now I see the mess below... `:(`

Comment: After the Great Meta Split, the link posted by @Antony no longer works. It's now http://meta.dev.stackexchange.com/content/js/full.js  (no idea why they flipped the order of meta and dev...)

Comment: Is there a solution to this bug? Or should it be ignored?

Comment: @edition It's [status-completed]

Comment: Have you notified the Mayo Clinic yet?

Answer (score 8):

*EDIT:  This question is about a bug that was fixed about about 2.5 years ago ([per Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177754/the-cardiologist-cant-tell-if-my-heart-is-beating/275700#comment893474_275700)), despite this question not appearing to have any submitted answers until now.*

> Stack Exchange has a cardiologist?

Yes, actually, in a way.  There has been a background object called "StackExchange.cardiologist".

> And it can't tell if my heart is beating?!

More precisely, the error you found means that the cardiologist cannot be found, not that the cardiologist can't tell if a heart is beating.  And the "heartbeat" being referenced is background communication between the StackExchange page in your browser and a StackExchange server.  "Heartbeat" is a bit of a misnomer for such meaningful communication.  But still, the communication is periodic (it happens regularly), just like a real animal's heartbeat.

> Are we in a Q&A site or an inexperienced hospital?

Haha --   But all jokes aside, a Q&A site.  A Q&A site with back-end programmers who come up with all kinds of names for the parameters and objects that are usually entirely behind-the-scenes.

> What is this strange error? ["Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isHeartBeating' of undefined"]

Beyond what was referenced above -- that there is code that cannot call the method 'isHeartBeating' because it doesn't have a valid connection or reference to a 'cardiologist' object -- beyond that, it's nothing to be too concerned about unless you're noticing problems in front-end functionality, like difficulty reading or posting a question, answer, or comment.  (And you haven't mentioned any such difficulty.)  Yes, it's a bug, and it's good to report such things, but it's more of a curiosity than a real problem based on the way the question has been phrased, no?

Reference:   [What is sent and received from the server during a "heartbeat" and how often does it beat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111581/what-is-sent-and-received-from-the-server-during-a-heartbeat-and-how-often-doe/111644#111644) (with thanks to @balpha for providing that link in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177754/the-cardiologist-cant-tell-if-my-heart-is-beating#comment535336_177754))

Comment: "Yes, it's a bug, and it's good to report such things, but it's more of a curiosity than a real problem based on the way the question has been phrased, no?" - it's also a bug that was fixed about 2.5 years ago. :) We appreciate hearing about all bugs, not just ones that are immediately apparent. There's degrees of severity, for sure, but a bug's a bug and leads to *some* broken functionality even if it's not dire.