# Status Bar updates - Sent by server or periodically checked by client?

Tags: discussion

I want to know whether the Status Bar of any StackExchange site (the topmost bar with the search window, chat, main, about, etc links) updates periodically by the requests/checks by the client i.e. users or does the StackExchange Server send these updates to online clients? Just curious about the implementation.

If the client checks for the updates periodically, then the server risks getting abused by constant requests.

While, if the server sends the updates it would be efficient but one would have to write quite some code for the server side.

**EDIT** - [Similar, but slightly different query beautifully answered here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71765/238020)

Comment: Last time I checked, the client polls the servers.

Comment: Thanks. Got a detailed answer here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71765/238020